# extract package and macros that use extract environments

Tags: tikz-cd, extract

I have a number of (long) documents from which I want to extract all of the `tikzpicture` environments into a separate file.

The `extract` package seems the right place to start, but there's a problem: `extract` finds instances of `tikzpicture` environments not just in the tex file, but (of course) in anything that gets expanded.

**Example document**

The following code has a `tikzpicture` in it, but also a `tikzcd` environment (which invokes a `tikzpicture`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,generate=testoutput,extract-env={tikzpicture}]{extract}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
Z  & n,m \arrow{r}{+ \text{ in }Z} \arrow[swap]{d}{\sigma} & n+m \arrow{d}{\sigma} \\
K  & n^*,m^* \arrow[swap]{r}{+ \text{ in }K} & (n+m)^* = n^*+m^*
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

This does not compile cleanly with the `extract` line uncommented, giving all sorts of issues with the `tikzcd` environment. The output file created looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[/tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every diagram,sep=huge]\ifx \arrow \tikzcd@arrow \pgfutil@packageerror {tikz-cd}{Diagrams cannot be nested}{}\fi \let \arrow \tikzcd@arrow \let \ar \tikzcd@arrow \def \rar {\tikzcd@xar {r}}\def \lar {\tikzcd@xar {l}}\def \dar {\tikzcd@xar {d}}\def \uar {\tikzcd@xar {u}}\def \urar {\tikzcd@xar {ur}}\def \ular {\tikzcd@xar {ul}}\def \drar {\tikzcd@xar {dr}}\def \dlar {\tikzcd@xar {dl}}\global \let \tikzcd@savedpaths \pgfutil@empty \matrix [/tikz/matrix of \iftikzcd@mathmode math \fi nodes,/tikz/every cell/.append code={\tikzcdset {every cell}},/tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every matrix]\bgroup 
Z  & n,m \arrow{r}{+ \text{ in }Z} \arrow[swap]{d}{\sigma} & n+m \arrow{d}{\sigma} \\
K  & n^*,m^* \arrow[swap]{r}{+ \text{ in }K} & (n+m)^* = n^*+m^*
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If we modify the code in the original tex file so that the `extract` package is called using the line

```
\usepackage[active,generate=testoutput,extract-env={tikzpicture,tikzcd}]{extract}
```

it doesn't work, but in a slightly different (albeit related) way.

The following *does*, of course, work:

```
\usepackage[active,generate=testoutput,extract-env={tikzcd}]{extract}
```

...but that doesn't extract normal tikzpictures.

If it were just the `tikzcd` environment that is causing trouble, I could almost certainly just replace it with a more vanilla tikz figure.

Unfortunately, the class file I am using has a number of predefined environments which use the `tikzpicture` environment to draw pretty boxes around things (theorems, exercises, that sort of thing), and these are also causing trouble.

The [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/extract/extract.pdf) for the `extract` package has some detail about conditionals, etc, but there seems little way to get round this (other than revert to writing a python script, which I'm loathe to do). Any suggestions?

Comment: why not python? I'd use perl or emacs lisp but python should be fine (and better than tex at editing files)

Comment: There are a few subtleties that make python tricky (not least I'd have to learn python first!). Another complexity is that there are bits of the TeX document (solutions to exercises) that get written to a file, then read back in at the end, and these also contain `tikzpicture` environments. To have the tikzpictures appear in the order they appear in the PDF, a python script would need do more than just pull out the `tikzpicture` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to extract some pictures, leaving aside all the auxiliary `tikzpicture` environments, you can use a different name for those you want to extract.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,generate=testoutput,extract-env={xtikzpicture}]{extract}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{xtikzpicture}{\begin{tikzpicture}}{\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{xtikzpicture}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
Z  & n,m \arrow{r}{+ \text{ in }Z} \arrow[swap]{d}{\sigma} & n+m \arrow{d}{\sigma} \\
K  & n^*,m^* \arrow[swap]{r}{+ \text{ in }K} & (n+m)^* = n^*+m^*
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `testoutput.tex` file will be

```latex
%%
%% This is file, `testoutput.tex',
%% generated with the extract package.
%%
%% Generated on :  2020/01/31,17:03
%% From source  :  extik.tex
%% Using options:  active,generate=testoutput,extract-env={xtikzpicture}
%%
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{xtikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You'll need to edit the generated file anyway, in order to make it usable.

Comment: This might be the best solution, thanks. It is super-simple, if not totally automatic (but then nothing is ever going to be truly automatic).

Comment: @rbrignall I think that `extract` changes the working of `\tikzpicture` and `\endtikzpicture` and obviously this affects any macro that internally calls them.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative response, the `ltximg` *script* automates this process, create *standalone* files (and images) for all `tikzpicture`.

The `ltximg` script you can do the following:

```
$ ltximg  --subenv --imgdir=mypics  --prefix=tkz -o test-out test.tex
```

Now you will have a new document `test-out.tex` with the `tikzpicture` environments
converted into images (`.pdf`) and you will also have each
`tikzpicture` environment in *standalone* files and one file `test-all.tex` with (only) all `tikzpicture`.

If your input file is `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
Z  & n,m \arrow{r}{+ \text{ in }Z} \arrow[swap]{d}{\sigma} & n+m \arrow{d}{\sigma} \\
K  & n^*,m^* \arrow[swap]{r}{+ \text{ in }K} & (n+m)^* = n^*+m^*
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `test-out.tex` file will look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{{mypics/}}
\usepackage{grfext}
\PrependGraphicsExtensions*{.pdf}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{test-tkz-1}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
Z  & n,m \arrow{r}{+ \text{ in }Z} \arrow[swap]{d}{\sigma} & n+m \arrow{d}{\sigma} \\
K  & n^*,m^* \arrow[swap]{r}{+ \text{ in }K} & (n+m)^* = n^*+m^*
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

And the *standalone* file `test-tkz-1.tex`, located in `./mypics`, will look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you only need to create the *standalone* files you can use:

```
$ ltximg  --subenv --imgdir=mypics --prefix=tkz --norun test.tex
```

First check the documentation to see the options and conditions
that the input file must meet.